# View all posts within a Google Apps domain

Tags: google-workspace, google-plus

My organization uses Google Apps, and Google+ is enabled.

My coworkers can share items with everyone in our Google Apps Domain, which is handy for sharing intra-organizational information.

Can I view all posts which were shared by coworkers within our Domain? For example, if our Domain was "University of Awesome", can I show all posts which were shared by members of this Domain?

I search for posts using a #hashtag, a keyword search, a Circle or an individual; but I would like to search for posts within our Google Apps "Domain".

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported natively or by the Google+ API.

Theoretically, one could provide a list of all domain users (or pull it via the Google+ API) and then attempt to [list "activities"](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list) (posts, reshares, etc) for each user. Note that the only "collection" currently supported is "public", which means you won't be able to pull private posts from any users.

Update 11/18:
Google recently implemented a new API ([here's](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/getting-started) a comparison with the existing API I referenced above) designed for exactly this purpose. You could modify the quickstart app ([Java](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/quickstart/java) or [Python](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/quickstart/python)), import a list of users (using a Google API or a list you have yourself), [iterate through each user's posts](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/posts/reading#getting_a_list_of_a_users_posts) and return the activity ID, then use that to [get post details](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/posts/reading#reading_a_specific_posts).

Answer (score 0):

Nice idea, but currently not supported.

See also Google's official help on "[Search in Google+](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1669519?hl=en)".

You could create a circle with all the domain's members, but in general that will only allow you to see the public posts.  (Of course, for members that have placed you inside one of their circles, you will also see private posts as well.)

Comment: Yosi, the circle will just make it easier for you to view the public posts in one place, right? Public posts are public, regardless of your individual circle settings.

Comment: Well, it will make it easy to view in one place the public posts of his domain users (while filtering out the public posts of his non-domain circle-members).  This is the "public half" of what the OP is looking for (with the "private half" not fully covered).  As I said: "not currently supported."